# How to open multiple editor views open in TornadoFX

Tags: kotlin, javafx, tornadofx

I've been following the guide [here](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/part1/11.%20Editing%20Models%20and%20Validation.html) where it gives an example of an editor using a ViewModel.

I'm looking to change this so that instead of a single editor that is rebound to each domain object for editing, instead each object will bring up its own separate editor.

I want to keep using the ViewModels as I like the separation they provide and the API they have (easy rollback / saving).

How should I handle opening an editor per domain object (especially in a TornadoFX way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create a new scope for the new editor and inserting the relevant models into that new scope. If you're using the Workspace, this is done using built in functions like `dockInNewScope`:

```
workspace.dockInNewScope<MyEditor>(myModel1, myModel2, etc)
```

If you're not using Workspace, you can create a new scope manually, put models into it and lookup views in the new scope as well:

```
val newScope = Scope(myModel1, myModel2)
find<MyEditor>(newScope).openWindow()
```

`MyEditor` will in this instance see `myModel` and `myModel2` in it's scope, so that it can inject them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Am I correct in thinking that each domain object needs its own ViewModel so I can't get away with just one? Edit: just implemented it with creating a new ViewModel before the editor is opened, works like a charm, thanks Edvin!

Comment: You can stuff all sorts of objects in a single viewmodel, but once you get into forms etc, you really want one for each domain object :)